# Add number of days to a date formatted in MySQL Date in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to add a certain number of days to a date formatted like 2010-10-17 without converting it to a unix timestamp like using the function strtotime in php?

Comment: You probably could, but why would you? Working with dates as strings means you have to do all the tedious date calculations yourself. What's wrong with `strtotime`?

Comment: well from my understanding in the year 2038 the timestamp will not work.

Comment: What sort of project are you working on that you need to worry about dates that far out?

Comment: and thats only true if you are running 32bit version of PHP (where time_t is 32 bits) - from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: @Andy That's what they said when they stored years using two digits... ;) Agree though that by the time 2038 rolls around, UNIX timestamps will hopefully be universally upgraded to use 64bit+ ints, so the app should continue to work transparently.

Comment: It is a reminder program for property leases which expire far into the future.  Plus it is a future proofing attempt for the code.  I can easily do it with a timestamp, I just wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: @deceze: "they said"?  I didn't say anything.  I specifically made no conclusions.  I asked about requirements, so that he can question the need to worry about things that far out.

Comment: @Andy Indeed, intention is a difficult thing to communicate on the internet... `<blink>`;)`</blink>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play around with the [DateTime library](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).

So, based on your description, something like the following should do the trick:

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-10-17');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D')); //adding ten days
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

**Outputs:** 2010-10-27

---

Although I'm curious as to why you do not want to work with timestamps? As they're the most flexible choice here.

Comment: This is a good solutions, and one that I considered, but it requires php 5.3.0 or greater.

Comment: Ah yes. Maybe you should edit the question to state this? Also, if you're working with an older version of PHP, than your best alternative would be to work with timestamps.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment, error in testing method... ^_^;;

Comment: ok.  It sounds like the consensus is to use timestamps.  That is what I will do.  I do think that the DateTime library is also a good option, so I will mark your answer.  Thank you to everyone for your suggestions.